# Selenium session not created exception error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am getting this error:

> "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception"

i have updated my chrome and driver also to latest version.but still getting same error.

```
package helloworld;

public class testfb {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webDriver.ChromeDriver", "C:\\minal\\drivers\\ChromeDriver.exe ");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add error trace to body not in title of your question

Comment: Where are your imports?  What version(s) are you using of Selenium and ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 0):

chrome driver system property is case sensitive.

use this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```